# Creating a TRadioGroup at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to create a TRadioGroup dynamically with 7 different RadioButtons.

RadioButtons as follows:

`Screws 12mm`

`Canned Peaches 250g`

`Refil Blue Pen`

`Tomatoes`

`Spaghetti`

`Twin Flex 5m`

`Clear glue 250ml`

Here's how I think it must look:

```
rgpOptions := TRadioGroup.Create(frmSale);
  rgpOptions.Parent := frmSale;
  rgpOptions.Left := 30;
  rgpOptions.Top := 100;
  rgpOptions.Width := 300;
  rgpOptions.Height := 140;
  rgpOptions.Visible := True;
  rgpOptions.Items.Add := (
                          1 := 'Screws 12mm';
                          2 := 'Canned Peaches 250g';
                          3 := 'Refil Blue Pen';
                          4 := 'Tomatoes';
                          5 := 'Spaghetti';
                          6 := 'Twin Flex 5mm';
                          7 := 'Clear Glue';
                          );
```

(BTW I **know** it doesn't compile, that is why I am asking)

Comment: Add the items one at a time rgpOptions.Items.Add('Screws 12mm'); rgpOptions.Items.Add('Canned Peaches 250g'); etc

Comment: Why was this downvoted twice?!?! I showed my research and my effort for doing this? Jeez

Comment: No idea, everybody must start being an expert I guess. Upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Items.Add` once for each button:

```
rgpOptions.Items.Add('Screws 12mm');
rgpOptions.Items.Add('Canned Peaches 250g');
// etc.
```

Or if you have the items in a string list already, with one line of text per button, you could write:

```
rgpOptions.Items.Assign(OptionsStringList);
```

Comment: Thanks man, sorry about that other question xD.. Was under an influence.... And I wasn't near Delphi..

Answer (score 5):

In case you're going to use something newer than Delphi 7, you're looking for the `AddStrings(TArray<String>)` method of `TStringList.Items` which allows you to add an `array of string` to the list of radiogroup items:

```
rgpOptions.Items.AddStrings(
    TArray<String>.Create(
        'Screws 12mm',
        'Canned Peaches 250g',
        'Refil Blue Pen',
        'Tomatoes',
        'Spaghetti',
        'Twin Flex 5m',
        'Clear glue 250ml'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you download and install GExperts (http://www.gexperts.org/download/).
You'll get a new menu and some extension of the context menu.

One of the new options is `<component to code>`

[image]

If you select a container component (like TPanel) it will create code for all the owned components as well.

Comment: That is actually very useful. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for that!